# Missing emails on my my laptop vs ipad

Tags: ipad, email, gmail

why am i receiving more emails (gmail) on my ipad than on my laptop. I seem to be getting more email posted to my Ipad than to my laptop.  This morning I received 7 more emails on my Ipad than on my laptop.  Granted they were websites that have something to sell but I have asked for these. Why are they not showing up on my laptop.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of laptop? What application are you using on the laptop to read email? Did you check the junk or spam folder of that application?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and there is nothing in the promotions tab, the social tab or the junk mail folder. It's very frustrating. I am logging in directly to Gmail and still can not see the emails that are on my iPad.

Comment: Furthermore, how is Gmail configured on your iPad?

Answer (score 1):

It's the new gmail interface. Right above the list of emails are three tabs:
Primary   Social    Promotion
You are in Primary, try clicking Promotion and you will see the missing emails.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, you don't say what laptop you have, what OS, what email client etc. My hunch is that local junk mail filtering is moving or hiding email on your laptop. Login direct to the gmail website as this will be the canonical source, and then find a missing email and search for it via keywords in its contents on your local mail client.